# Selecting IO scheduler on external drives

Tags: linux, embedded, io

I'm running linux on the beaglebone black.  My system is running directly from the sdcard.  To change the IO scheduler I need to configure /sys/block/xxx/queue/scheduler where xxx is the mounted drive.  However there are only entries for mmc and ram in the /sys/block folder.
How do I change the IO scheduler for my system mounted on sdcard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have **2 ways** to setup the IO scheduler on Linux.

You **defined a default IO scheduler** for all block devices. You can do this by adding the parameter `elevator=<scheduler>` (e.g. `elevator=deadline`) to your boot prompt (if you use a recent Grub version, like v1.99 or 2.0, you can add this in the file /etc/default/grub, look for the parameter `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` which should be a list of parameters separated by spaces, and add the mentionned parameter).

If you want the **IO scheduler to be specific to your SD Card**, look for the corresponding `mmc*` block device and set it during boot using your init system. E.g. `echo "deadline" > /sys/block/mmcblk0/queue/scheduler` (which is btw the default value on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian for my Micro SD Card)